# Selenium Webdriver : Code not working on IE11

Tags: internet-explorer, selenium

I am operation on window 7 - 32 bit system. The code which i am running runs well when run on Chrome and Firefox. But he code doesnt work on IE - 11.

The browser is opened and the application is launched but it is not able to find any element on the page as a result no such element exception is thrown.

I have also done the following additional setting as mentioned for IE11

**(For IE 11 only, you will need to set a registry entry on the target computer so that the driver can maintain a connection to the instance of Internet Explorer it creates. For 32-bit Windows installations, the key you must examine in the registry editor is HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BFCACHE. For 64-bit Windows installations, the key is HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BFCACHE. Please note that the FEATURE_BFCACHE subkey may or may not be present, and should be created if it is not present. Inside this key, create a DWORD value named iexplore.exe with the value of 0.)**

It is also said that enhanced protected mode should be disabled. But i cannot find that setting.

Is their anyone who can help me.

Answer (score 0):

Disabling Enhanced Protected Mode is easy. Open up your Internet Explorer browser and navigate to your internet options menu. It is located under the "Advanced" tab.

I'm pretty sure you're running IEDriver, but just in case, here is the installation instructions and documentation for it.

https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver

Let me know if you need additional help.

Comment: I have checked the advanced tab but their it is not present

Comment: I checked few articles where they say that enhanced protected mode  is not present in win 7 - 32 bit - ie 11 users is it true. in that case how to run the code

Comment: http://news.thewindowsclub.com/microsoft-releases-update-disable-enhanced-protected-mode-internet-explorer-11-66389/#comment-1133985271  came across this link